# How to create a server in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

How can I create a server script that will know if there is/are file/s existing in a folder? If it detect/s that there is/are files existing in the said folder, it will create a manifest file with details below then compress the file/s excluding the manifest file. *This script will be executed at a certain time and will perform the said operations on a timely basis.*

Below are the details:

**Manifest File Format**

- File Extension: *.manifest*
- Manifest content: *filename|filesize|recordcount|createddate|lastmodified|md5|*

**Where:**

- Filename = *filename*
- Filesize = *file size in byte size without a comma (e.g. 34KB should
  be written as 34000 and not 34,000)*
- Record count = *record count without a comma*
- Createddate = *yyyymmddhh24miss*
- Lastmodified = *yyyymmddhh24miss*
- md5 = *using md5sum in linux to get the md5 value.*

**One (1) manifest file for each transfer/batch of files.**

- Multiple files can be archived into one (1) file excluding the
  manifest file.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

This is what I've done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Filename: "
read filename
if
    ls -l $filename
then
    echo "File found!"
    manifest=$""batch_"$(date +%Y%m%d)."manifest""
    du -b $filename | awk '{printf "| " $2 " | "}' >> "$manifest"
    du -b $filename | awk '{printf $1 " | "}' >> "$manifest"
    wc -l $filename | awk '{printf $1 " | "}' >> "$manifest"
    md5sum $filename | awk '{printf $1 " |"}' >> "$manifest"
    zip -r "batch_"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).".zip" $filename
fi
echo "Done."
```

Comment: Please edit this question to include some code blocks or quotes to make it easier to read.

Comment: I already edited the post.

Comment: It's a maintenance nightmare when you keep repeating the same code - if you are going to do something more than once, put it in a variable, e.g. `OUT=$(date +'batch_%Y%m%d%H%M%S.manifest')` and then do `echo >> "$OUT"`.

Comment: How can I get to optimize my shell script? Also how can I get to put multiple properties in a single manifest?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple web server written in Bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
RESPONSE="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n${2:-"OK"}\r\n"
while { echo -en "$RESPONSE"; } | nc -l "${1:-8080}"; do
echo "================================================"
done
```

From [GitHub / Shinatra](https://github.com/benrady/shinatra/blob/master/shinatra.sh)